# Byte order for OpenCV 2.1 cvLoadImage?

Tags: opencv

Am using cvLoadImage from OpenCV 2.1 on Windows to load a .bmp file.  (legacy app, maintaining code, not new development.)

Is it loading it in RGB or BGR order?  Documentation http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html does not say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual order is BGR.Try this code with your own single pixel image.

```
IplImage *img = cvLoadImage("c:\\pixel.bmp");
CvScalar s;
s=cvGet2D(img,0,0);
cout << s.val[0];  //first color value (blue)
cout << s.val[1];  //second color value (green)
cout << s.val[2];  //third color value (red)
```

Comment: It returns whatever byte order is the standard for that image type. Windows bitmaps are generally BGR

Comment: @ahoffer, my plan was to do just what you suggested.  You are correct.